# Tess-two + "tessdata_fast" : crashes

Tags: android, android-ndk, tesseract, tess-two

I am using tess-two for OCR.

The version I use is : https://github.com/alexcohn/tess-two

Code:

```
        TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
        baseApi.setDebug(true);
        baseApi.init(pathfiles, language);
        baseApi.setVariable(TessBaseAPI.VAR_CHAR_WHITELIST, "0123456789");
        baseApi.setPageSegMode(TessBaseAPI.PageSegMode.PSM_AUTO);
        baseApi.setImage(bmp);
        result= baseApi.getUTF8Text();
        baseApi.end();
```

The code run perfectly when I use this tessdata :https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata

But when I use tessdata_fast (https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata_fast), The code crashes on baseApi.init.

There is no error message since the init method calls native C++. As far as I can trace, the init method crashes on this line:

```
boolean success = nativeInitOem(mNativeData, datapath, language, ocrEngineMode);
```

Is it possible to use tessdata_fast in tess-two?

Comment: I  also changed the the OEM like this:
baseApi.init(pathfiles, language, TessBaseAPI.OEM_CUBE_ONLY);
but it still crashes.

I tried all the OEM parameters I can find :
(OEM_TESSERACT_ONLY = 0,  OEM_CUBE_ONLY = 1, OEM_TESSERACT_CUBE_COMBINED = 2, OEM_DEFAULT = 3)
They crashes on the same line.

Comment: `fast` and `best` data are for Tesseract 4.x. Does your tess-two use that version?

Comment: I use this version :https://github.com/alexcohn/tess-two.  The web page says "This project works with:Tesseract 4.1 (submodule)".

Comment: `fast` and `best` modules does not have legacy (3x) engine, so that is reason why is crash. `CUBE` is removed for 4x. version, so you can not use it with 4 modules.

Comment: I see. However, There is no OEM value other than those four in tess-two (Again, the version I use is https://github.com/alexcohn/tess-two, 9.0.0). Do I miss any thing?

Comment: It could be that tess-two version is not up to date.